# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column in magento

Tags: magento

After installation FME layered navigation https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/fma_layerednavigation making below error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'final_price' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT MIN(price_idx.min_price) AS `min_value`, MAX(price_idx.min_price) AS `max_value` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '10'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_idx` ON price_idx.entity_id=e.entity_id WHERE ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND ((1=1 ) OR (final_price is NULL)) AND (price_idx.website_id = '1') AND (price_idx.customer_group_id = 0) LIMIT 36

Answer (score 0):

Column 'final_price' is ambigous because mysql query need to know this column belong to which table you have to use table alias for that like this price_index.final_price replace all final_price to price_index.final_price